# Influence Function of M-Estimator

Tags: probability, distributions, estimators, m-estimation, influence-function

I know the following influence function for a M-Estimator:

$IF(x_0,T,F_0)= $ $\frac{\psi(x_0)}{\mathbb{E}_{F_0}[\psi'(X)]}$

where $F_0$ is the centered model ($F_{\theta}(x)=F_0(x-\theta)$)

I am interested in knowing the influence function for the general model:

$IF(x,T,F_{\mu,\sigma})$

I know that it must be

$IF(x,T,F_{\mu,\sigma})= $ $\frac{\psi(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})\sigma}{\mathbb{E}_{F_0}[\psi'(X)]}$

I dont know how to obtain that, any hint would be welcome.

Edit:

The influence function describes the effect of an infinitesimal contamination at the point $x$ on the estimate we are seeking, for a given distribution $F$:

$$IF(x,T,F)=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{T((1-t)F+t\Delta_x)-T(F)}{t}$$

A location M-estimator is defined as the solution in $t$ of the equation:

$$\sum^{n}_{i} \psi(\frac{x_i-t}{s_n})=0$$ where $s_n$ is an equivariant scale estimator.

We define $F_0$ as the centered model:

$$F_{\mu,\sigma}(x)=F_0(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})$$

I know that the influence function, in the centered model, at a point $x_0$ for a location M-estimator is given by:

$$IF(x_0,T,F_0)=\frac{\psi(x_0)}{\mathbb{E}_{F_0}[\psi'(X)]}$$

I am trying to prove that

$$IF(x,T,F_{\mu,\sigma})=\frac{\psi(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})\sigma}{\mathbb{E}_{F_0}[\psi'(X)]}$$

Furthermore, I know that:

$$s_n(X+b)=s_n(X)$$
$$s_n(aX)=a s_n(X)$$
Location M-estimator are equivariant:

$$T(aX+b)=aT(x)+b$$

Any help would be really appreciated, Ive been stuck on this for too long...

Comment: Some explanation of your notation will help almost all readers understand your question and expedite the appearance of a useful answer.

Comment: 1. The influence function is typically for a single parameter; in your "general model" you have two parameters  ($\mu$ and $\sigma$.)  Is this what you want? 2. There is no loss of generality if we set $\mu = 0, \sigma = 1$ in the location-scale case, not even for influence functions.

Comment: @jbowman I added some clarifications